# Override value css

Tags: html, css, datatables

I have this class used in many section: dt-buttons btn-group

My code

```
<div class="dt-buttons btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-align-right btn-primary" tabindex="0" aria-controls="specificationsTable">
        <span>Add specifications</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I search when the class: btn-align-righ is there and the parent is: dt-buttons btn-group

to put value: float:right

Actually for dt-buttons btn-group value is float:left... when I put btn-align-righ I would like to override value this value

tried without success

```
div.dt-buttons btn-group button.btn-align-right{
    float:right;
}
```

Create a demo here
http://jsfiddle.net/wj4msayt/

Comment: If you're just trying to align the button on the right, do `div.dt-buttons.btn-group { width: 100%; justify-content: flex-end; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

The `float-right` needs to be applied to the `btn-group` class rather than the `button` itself.

I've updated your fiddle and fixed the issue - [`Updated Fiddle :D`](http://jsfiddle.net/umaedv5L/17/)

**EDIT -** *Alternative method to meet OP's new conditions -*

**Option 2:**

Add the below-given code to your stylesheet and script respectively:

```
div.move-right {
  float: right;
}

$('#specificationsTable_wrapper .btn-group').addClass('move-right');
```

Basically, with this code you are gonna target your specific button group using jQuery and add the class to move the button to the right.

P.S. [`float`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) style for the button will only work if it is applied to any container which is having it. Adding it to the button won't have any effect.

Comment: the problem that affect all button.... that why I added btn-align-right...

Comment: @roberttrudel I've added another way to float the button to the right which will target only that specific `btn-group` and help solve the issue. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine both class selectors with . and without space.
Try the below code

```
div.dt-buttons.btn-group button.btn-align-right{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: @roberttrudel, can you please add a plunker.

Comment: created a demo at jsfiddle